# PayPal Webservice for TransactionSearch does not respect StartDate/EndDate

Tags: c#, paypal

I am struggling with a call to PayPal's Webservice to execute a TransactionSearch like shown here:

```
AccountType accountType = AccountType.Live;
tblPayPalAccount account = PayPalAPICallHelperSOAP.GetAccount(accountType);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);


using (PayPalAPIInterfaceClient client = new PayPalAPIInterfaceClient())
{
    client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0");
    UserIdPasswordType userIdPasswordType = PayPalAPICallHelperSOAP.GetUserIdPasswordType(account);
    CustomSecurityHeaderType header = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
    header.Credentials = userIdPasswordType;

    TransactionSearchReq request = new TransactionSearchReq();

    request.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();

    request.TransactionSearchRequest.Version = account.version;
    request.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = startDate;

    request.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = endDate;

    TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponseType = client.TransactionSearch(ref header, request);
}
```

I always get 67 results starting from today, regardless what value I pass to StartDate/EndDate (in this case it is 2012 but I only get values for the last few weeks)

Am I missing something? This is really bugging me for quite a while now and regardless what I set, the result is always the same.

Comment: Could it be because you swapped your `startDate` and `endDate`?

Comment: I had the same thought an hour ago, but it doesn't change anything if I swapped them, it always returns the same result.

Comment: Funny is that it returns nothing for the specified year (2012), only 2013 and from today it goes backwards...

I double checked it online and there are more than 100 results for 2012.

using the SDK it works fine, it only fails when I use the webservice...

Comment: Perhaps if you set it to UTC specifically?

Comment: I tried to use DateTime.SpecifyKind for both (StartDate/EndDate), the current and the swapped versions, but it still returns the same result :(

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same problem right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDateSpecified = true;
```

Tell the webservice that the end date is set. This solves your problem. No idea why it is required.